# $f’(x)=\arcsin(x^2), y=f\left( \frac{x-1}{x+1} \right)$. What is $~\frac{dy}{dx}?$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> $f’(x)=\arcsin(x^2), ~~y=f\left( \dfrac{x-1}{x+1} \right)~$. What is $~\dfrac{dy}{dx}~?$

I am quite confused of the arcsin thing, there is no direct way to get $f(x)$ from this $f’(x)$.  Then how to solve it ?

Comment: Have you learned the chain rule?

Comment: @erik I know how to solve. really stupid question  .   Just the chain rule .    Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$~\dfrac{dy}{dx}~= f^\prime\left( \frac{x-1}{x+1} \right)\left( \frac{x-1}{x+1} \right)^\prime$$ $$ =\frac{(x+1)-(x-1)}{(x+1)^2}\arcsin((\frac{x-1}{x+1})^2)$$ $$=\frac{2}{(x+1)^2}\arcsin((\frac{x-1}{x+1})^2)$$